# Php, add and subtract timestamps, get minutes

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I need to get different time lengths in minutes from a few timestamps that are:

- starttime
- endtime
- starttime2nd
- endtime2nd

---

**Edit**: clarification:
Each time is originally stored as a datetime string, like

`"2018-02-21T19:45:13+00:00"`.

I take that and convert it to `strtotime("2018-02-21T19:45:13+00:00");`

And from that I get a timestamp : `1519242313`

---

It doesn't seem that I can use plus or minus operators to add or subtract timestamps, like:

$length = ($endtime2nd - $starttime2nd) + ($endtime - $starttime)

Am I required to instantiate **DateTime** and use the "`->diff`" method to get a time interval?

I could get one time interval by doing this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime();

$starttime= $date1->setTimestamp($starttime);
$endtime= $date2->setTimestamp($endtime);

$length = $endtime->diff($starttime);
```

Does this mean that I need to instantiate **four** DateTimes to get the total length, and set four timestamps, then get the "`->diff`" for the two time intervals, and then add them using the "`->add`" method of DateTime method?

I would just like to know if there is a simpler method?

Comment: *"It doesn't seem that I can use plus or minus operators to add or subtract timestamps"* How did you come to that conclusion? If it's a simple unix timestamp (as a number) there is nothing preventing you from using simple math on those values. Have you `var_dump`ed them to see what type they are?

Comment: If I take the timestamps and do $t4 - $t3  I get 0. On the other hand if I take just the strings , 1519245110 - 1519242313, it does seem to work. I don't know why I get 0 when calculating them as timestamps(?) . How do I work with them like strings?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not showing your whole code. For now it's quite simple. If you have two variables containing numbers, you can do math with them. https://3v4l.org/5sE46   If this does not *seem* to work for you, then your variables are not what you think they are.

Comment: Or a more direct example: https://3v4l.org/3lg0D

Comment: Ok, I had a mistake in my testing code on phpfiddle, and originally I didn't get anything when testing with die($t4 - $t3) . I thouht it would display the time using "die()" but it goes blank. (it works with echo though). So I guess I can calculate with timestamps after all, thanks!

Comment: I see. Check [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php#refsect1-function.exit-parameters) for why die/exit didn't work (hint: don't use integers).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to instantiate DateTime and use the "->diff" method, because you already have timestamp (as i can see you are using `setTimestamp`)

```
<?php
    $length = ($endtime2nd - $starttime2nd) + ($endtime - $starttime);

    echo round(abs($length / 60), 2). " minute";
?>
```

Comment: No, the times come from strtotime() timestamps

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total minuts like this.

```
$min = $length->d * 24 * 60;
$min = $min + $length->h * 60;
$min = $min + $length->m;
```